# Please suggest correct regular expression for below situation

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have following response section.

```
<a href="/Public/Details/06S?OID=2" title="Click to view details">06S</a>
                </td><td>
                    <img src="/Media/Images/Opr/2.png" title="Pa" />
                </td><td style="0">
                    4
                </td>
```

I want to extract 06S and 2 only if value in between  tag is NOT 0.

I wrote following regular expression but it does not work. could anyone please help.

```
(?s)<a href="/Public/Details/(.+)?OID=(.+?)" title="Click to view details">(.+?)</a>
                </td><td>
                    <img src="/Media/Images/Opr/(.+?).png" title="(.+?)" />
                </td><td style="0">
                    ([1-9]{1})
                </td>
```

Comment: Even your regex is also working after removing first unwanted pattern. Try this, title="Click to view details">(.+?)<\/a>
                <\/td><td>
                    <img src="\/Media\/Images\/Opr\/(.+?).png" title="(.+?)" \/>
                <\/td><td style="0">
                    ([1-9]{1})
                <\/td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put a lot of time into making this pretty or anything but this will do what you asked.

```
<a href="\/Public\/Details\/(.+?)\?OID=(.+?)" .*?>.*?<\/a>\s*<\/td><td>\s*<img.*?\/>\s*<\/td><td.*?>\s*(?:[^\s0]|[^\s]{2,})?\s*<\/td>
```

This assumes that your data is coming in an extremely similar way that you posted in the question. I'm a little preoccupied so I couldn't make it much better.

obligatory [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wF4nI0/3) link

Comment: @Maitray Bhatt, if this helped you, you should accept it as an answer.